# Python Tkinter listbox alignment

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

What is the best way to align a listbox as the following?

```
   1     7.56
   2   115.07
 ...
  10   789.00
 ...
 100     0.01
 ...
1000    17.77
```

Could someone please explain to me how to achieve this alignment?

Comment: Python doesn't have list boxes.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I meant python tkinter

Comment: You mean you want a listbox with several columns? Tkinter does not have that. You can put 2 listboxes next to each other or you can use the `ttk.Treeview` widget.

Answer (score 2):

After working all night, I came up with this solution.

```
if data < 10:
    self.listbox.insert(END, "   {:>}    {:>8}".format(n, data))
elif data < 100:
    self.listbox.insert(END, "   {:>}   {:>8}".format(n, data))
elif data < 1000:
    self.listbox.insert(END, "   {:>}  {:>8}".format(n, data))
else:
    self.listbox.insert(END, "   {:>} {:>8}".format(n, data))
```

By the way, my listbox has

```
self.listbox.configure(justify=RIGHT)
```